# Quartz JDBCJobStore configuration with mysql

Tags: java, quartz-scheduler

I am new to quartz. i configured jdbcjobstore with mysql with below configuration.
Its working fine if i create a scheduler via java.

```
# Main Quartz configuration
org.quartz.scheduler.skipUpdateCheck = true
org.quartz.scheduler.instanceName = DatabaseClusteredScheduler
org.quartz.scheduler.instanceId = AUTO
org.quartz.scheduler.jobFactory.class = org.quartz.simpl.SimpleJobFactory
org.quartz.jobStore.class = org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreTX
org.quartz.jobStore.driverDelegateClass = org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.StdJDBCDelegate
org.quartz.jobStore.dataSource = quartzDataSource
org.quartz.jobStore.tablePrefix = QRTZ_
org.quartz.jobStore.isClustered = true
org.quartz.threadPool.class = org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool
org.quartz.threadPool.threadCount = 5

# JobStore: JDBC jobStoreTX
org.quartz.dataSource.quartzDataSource.driver = com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
org.quartz.dataSource.quartzDataSource.URL = jdbc:mysql://192.168.1.2:3306/fatdb
org.quartz.dataSource.quartzDataSource.user = root
org.quartz.dataSource.quartzDataSource.password = root
org.quartz.dataSource.quartzDataSource.maxConnections = 8
```

my question is it's possible to put entries(like scheduler, job and other info ) directly on particular Quartz tables without writing program.

eg 
i am getting particular time from the user if i insert the time and appropriate scheduler details into quartz tables and if i call the listener with above config, does it work?

if it will works which are tables and what are the fields i need to configure.

Comment: I have written a blog post on Quartz that uses a REST API to schedule jobs and uses liquibase to manage database migrations.    http://juliuskrah.com/tutorial/2017/10/06/persisting-dynamic-jobs-with-quartz-and-spring/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out and it works. I inserted values only into 3 tabels and it was working preety well. Tables you need to configure:[QRTZ_JOB_DETAILS], [QRTZ_TRIGGERS] and [QRTZ_CRON_TRIGGERS].

Answer (score 4):

You should not directly write to quartz database via SQL.

[Quartz Best Practices](http://quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/best-practices)

> **JDBC JobStore**
>    
>  Never Write Directly To Quartz's Tables
>    
>    
> Writing scheduling data directly to the database (via SQL) rather than
>    
> using scheduling API:
>    
>    
> Results in data corruption (deleted data, scrambled data) 
>    
> Results in job seemingly "vanishing" without executing when a trigger's fire time arrives
>    
> Results in job not executing "just sitting there" when a when a trigger's fire time arrives
>    
> May result in: Dead-locks 
>    
> Other strange problems and data corruption